# How to change the color of skeleton in Kinect SDK 1.8?

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

As the question, i don't know how to change the color of the skeleton in Skeleton - Basic WPF ? Can any body help me

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the code in the Skeleton Sample, you can change the values in these brushes:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Brush used for drawing joints that are currently tracked
    /// </summary>
    private readonly Brush trackedJointBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 68, 192, 68));

    /// <summary>
    /// Brush used for drawing joints that are currently inferred
    /// </summary>        
    private readonly Brush inferredJointBrush = Brushes.Yellow;
```

To whatever RGB values or whatever predefined colors in `Brushes` eg.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Brush used for drawing joints that are currently tracked (red)
    /// </summary>
    private readonly Brush trackedJointBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0));

    /// <summary>
    /// Brush used for drawing joints that are currently inferred
    /// </summary>        
    private readonly Brush inferredJointBrush = Brushes.Blue;
```